# How to resize UITableViewCell with variable content?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Assuming a subclass A of UITableViewCell which has two states:
1.) Show some header (height: 0-50px)
2.) Show some header (height: 0-50px) + UITableView (height: 50-150px) (both within the subclassed UITableViewCell)

Exactly one cell of A can be in state 2, therefore of height 200px. All other cells are in state 1, therefore of height 50px.

Subclass A is implemented with IB and has a default size of 200px.

The controller which manages the UITableView keeps which cell is in state 2.

Question: How to change height based on state?

I did implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath` as follows:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    if (self.openTab && indexPath.row == self.openTab.row) {
       return 200.0;
    } else {
       return 50.0;
    }
 }
```

It doesn't work.

In addition, I tried to adjust height in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"conversationTableViewCell";
   ConversationTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
      [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ConversationTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
      cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }

   if (self.openTab && indexPath.row == self.openTab.row) {
      CGRect frame = cell.contentView.bounds;
      frame.size.height = 200.0;
      cell.contentView.bounds = frame;

   } else {
      CGRect frame = cell.contentView.bounds;
      frame.size.height = 50.0;
      cell.contentView.bounds = frame;
   }

   return cell;
}
```

Besides changing the height of the contentView's bounds, I also applied that idea to the frame and to both bounds/frame of UITableView within subclass A directly. I also experiemented with a few other methods (see commented section). Nothing works.

Any ideas how to get this done?

Comment: Where is the code that sets self.openTab property?

Comment: in the same class as the code shown, i can ensure that the conditional works properly...

Comment: So what exactly is not working? Does your `heightForCell` get called for the openTab cell?

Comment: yes, it gets called, and the correct value for height is returned, but the view doesn't reflect the height, it's always 200px as set in interface builder, no matter if height of 50px or 200px gets returned...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it by resizing UITableView, which has been added to contentView of subclass A, manually in `layoutSubviews`, like so:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
  [super layoutSubviews];

  if (self.openTab) {
    CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 150.0;
    self.tableView.frame = frame;
  } else {
    CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 0;
    self.tableView.frame = frame;
  }
}
```

EDIT: It's also important to add the view (e.g. UITableView) programatically to UITableViewCell instead of using IB in order to be able to change it's size.

Answer (score 0):

If you conditional is right, your first code must work. probably you forgot

```
self.tableview.delegate = self
```

and it doesn't pass for this method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];    
    self.tableView.delegate=self;
}
```

and your code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    if (self.openTab && indexPath.row == self.openTab.row) {
       return 200.0;
    } else {
       return 50.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: conditional works properly... delegate is set correct as well... i can even log the height of the cell/tableview and it returns the right value as expected, but the view doesn't reflect the height...

Comment: I don't know what i say. I have just made an example it works perfectly. In my example I did the next step: 1. create a tableview in the storyboard and set delegate and datasource 2. y put this method: `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row%2 == 0) {
        return 200.0;
    } else {
        return 50.0;
    }
}`  That's all.